# Is there a summary of Nobilis 3rd edition rules for new players?

Tags: new-players, system-introduction, nobilis

I want to start a game of Nobilis, but the 3rd edition book is huge (more than 300 pages) and I clearly can't ask my players to read it, even only the rules chapters.

I found [What are the basics of the Nobilis 2e system's mechanics, in a nutshell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140619/what-are-the-basics-of-the-nobilis-2e-systems-mechanics-in-a-nutshell) but it is only about the 2nd edition. Having read both I feel like the 3rd edition rules are quite better (even if the 2nd book is a wondrous object).

Is there any good summary of Nobilis 3rd edition rules for new players?

Answer (score 2):

I found some documents:

- [So You've Been EnNobled](http://www.mygurps.com/pics/So_Youve_Been_EnNobled.pdf)
- [a basic rules summary](https://rpgist.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/nobilis-rules-summary1.pdf) and the same [for miracles levels](https://rpgist.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/nobilis-miracle-levels3.pdf)
- [another basic summary in a single page](http://www.mygurps.com/Nobilis_3e_Character_Sheet_Back.pdf)

Comment: We want our answers to be more than just links to other resources, Imma suggest you incorporate the essence of those resources into this answer.